# Changing element CSS height with jQuery 2.3 vs. 3.3

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change the height of an element as a fixed ratio of its width with jQuery. It works with jQuery 2.3, but not with jQuery 3.3?

JS:

```
function makehorizontal() {
    var myWidth = jQuery('.horizontaled').width();
    var myHeight = myWidth / 1.6 + 'px';
    $('.horizontaled').css('height', myHeight);
}
$(window).load(function() {
    makehorizontal();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    makehorizontal();
});
```

CSS:

```
.image-background-holder{
    width:100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    position:relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="image-background-holder horizontaled">
...
</div><!--image-background-holder-->
```

Comment: does it give an error in the console or just doesn't work?

Comment: no error, just does not work ..

Comment: What happens if you manually call `makehorizontal()` in the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do believe that load, unload, and error have depreciated and are no longer in jquery 3.  You should use `.on` to register event listeners now so you could probably just change

```
$(window).load(function() {
    makehorizontal();
});
```

to

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    makehorizontal();
});
```

if that doesn't work maybe just use document ready like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    makehorizontal();
});
```

Here is a snippet of it working:

```js
function makehorizontal() {
    var myWidth = jQuery('.horizontaled').width();
    var myHeight = myWidth / 1.6 + 'px';
    $('.horizontaled').css('height', myHeight);
}
$(window).on( 'load', function () {
    makehorizontal();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    makehorizontal();
});
```

```css
.image-background-holder{
    width:100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    position:relative;
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <div class="image-background-holder horizontaled">
...
</div><!--image-background-holder-->
```

Comment: can also combine them using `on()`...  `$(window).on('load resize', makehorizontal)`

Comment: thanks Steve, but unfortunately no success for any of your suggestions ..

Comment: @rainerbrunotte I added a snippet of it working so if it is not working for you there's a possibility that you have some errors in your javascript.  Are there any errors in your console?